# Navbar bottom view getting cut off when browser window is smaller

Tags: html, css

So I have this navbar that I like and when the window is full size it sits perfectly on top of my two horizontal lines and looks great,  but when I resize it to a smaller view the words get cut off on the bottom.  I assume it has something to do with the height % but I'm stumped.  I also don't understand why 5% is the magic number that sits perfectly on top of the horizontal line tags when it full screen mode?

HTML:

```
<center><div class="navbar"><a href= 'ask.php'>Ask a Question</a>
      &nbsp;
        <a href='index.html'>Log out</a>
        &nbsp;

       <a href= 'search.html'>Search</a>
       &nbsp;

       <a href= 'yourqs.php'>Your Questions</a>
       &nbsp;
       <a href= 'test.php'>All Questions</a>


<hr><hr></div></center>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 5%;

 padding-top: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because 5% - in 1000px - and 5% in 100px, not the same

you can remove this height and set padding-top and padding-bottom for your div, or set height in 'px'

Comment: or use 'line-height' for your .navbar

Comment: Ok thank you,  I'll work on this and get back to you.

Comment: well that was simple haha.  Thanks I just just took height away and added padding-bottom.  Thanks I'll give you the answer in a few min when it allows me to.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question though.  On the left of the navbar there is a little gap where the background shows through?  I don't know why, the right side covers the whole screen?

Comment: @do734 remove margin from body
https://jsfiddle.net/3zxw2w8u/

and for future u can use reset.css


for example https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css

Comment: cool I figured it out,  jut did "margin-left: -10px"  did the trick.  Cheers!

Comment: @do734 yep this woks to but one of your block has margin-left - just remove it